# Is there a 'Velocity' attribute and is it possible to set it in python?

Tags: python

I have a mesh that is animated via python data. However, since it's python data there is no motion blur so there's not a good sense of motion. I know particles have velocity attributes, do vertices also have a velocity attribute I can set which will affect motion blur?

Comment: I found this Blender Dev ticket: https://developer.blender.org/T50107

Looks like it was never implemented. I also found this article where it appears like you can read the velocity, but you just can't write to it: https://blenderartists.org/t/custom-properties-for-vertices/588692

Comment: Thanks for the legwork. I'll try the developer forum and see if they have any input.

Comment: You can implement motion blur in compositing but for having velocities separately you can use the definition of velocity

$$\vec{v} = \frac{d\vec{x}}{dt}$$

Comment: @MohammadHosseinJamshidi oh wow, I didn't know mathjax works in comments, that's a game changer :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I don't have a perfect solution, but a workaround. You can simulate the *vector* pass and put it in the *vector blur* node.

## Set the attribute.

To store the data, I created an attribute, type - vector, domain - points:

[image]

Data is accessible for edit using Python. Of course, you have to calculate the vector by yourself, but from your question, I've deducted that's not a problem. Just for example, let's suppose that object moves up:

```
import bmesh
import bpy
from mathutils import Vector

me = bpy.context.object.data

# this line works only in edit mode, make sure that you in edit mode.
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)

ea = bm.verts.layers.float_vector['MyVector']

# for testing, let's object move up:
for v in bm.verts:
    v[ea]=Vector((0,0,1))

bmesh.update_edit_mesh(me)
```

## From World to screen space.

Next task is to transfer the attribute to compositor.

I've used Cycles' AOV for this. Set new layer here:

[image]

Then add *AOV output* in the shader:

[image]

In order to convert the vector from 3D space to screen space, use a *Vector Transform* node.

## Compose.

The last step is compositing. In Vector pass two vectors are used, first is difference between current and previous frame, second between current and next one. For demo, I just used the same vector twice, but if you want you can try to improve it.

So 2 vectors are packed in RGBA: first vector x ⇾ R, y ⇾ G, Second x ⇾ B, y ⇾ A. You can pack them using *Separate RGBA* and *Combine RGBA* nodes.

[image]

For some reason, vector is limited in rendering to 1, so to deal with it, I multiplied them in compositor.

So this is some kind of workaround, as you see, but I hope it'll help.

Comment: Since I'm animating points this actually might look pretty good. Thanks my guy.